# how can i free a Tpanel That have a TbitBtn that calls to free the Tpanel

Tags: windows, delphi, components, delphi-7

I create a Custom Tpanel and inside I put various Custom Components ...

```
procedure Panel_Comp(Location: TWinControl; NumOfComp:     Integer;Left,Top,Height,width:Integer);  
begin  
  MyPanel := TsPanel.Create(Conf);  
  MyPanel.Name := 'MyPanel' + IntToStr(NumOfComp);  
  MyPanel.Parent := Location;  
  MyPanel.Left := Left;  
  MyPanel.Top := Top;  
  MyPanel.Height := Height;  
  MyPanel.Width := width;  
  MyPanel.Caption := '';  
end;
```

and i call it like this

```
Panel_Comp(Conf.ScrollBox1,1,8,10,70,322);
```

in the same logic i put inside the new panel other custom components including a tBitbtn the have a onclick event..

```
procedure BitBtn_Comp(Location: TWinControl; NumOfComp: Integer; Left,Top,Height,Width,ImageNum: Integer);  
begin  
  MyBitBtn := TBitBtn.Create(Conf);  
  ......  
  MyBitBtn.tag := NumOfComp;  
  MyBitBtn.OnClick:= Conf.CloseCurrentPanel;
end;
```

In the main Forn The TConf.CloseCurrentPanel;

```
procedure TConf.CloseCurrentPanel(Sender: TObject);  
var  
  panelComp: TComponent;  
begin  
  panelComp := FindComponentEx('Conf.MyPanel'+ IntToStr(TBitBtn(Sender).tag);
  TPanel(panelComp).Free;
  Application.ProcessMessages;  
end;
```

When I call that I get access violation... 
I think is something that I must free all the components inside the panel before free the panel but how I free the BitBtn before the panel and continue the action of the click event?

Here is the FindComponetEx function instead you need it...

```
function FindComponentEx(const Name: string): TComponent;  
var  
  FormName: string;  
  CompName: string;  
  P: Integer;  
  Found: Boolean;  
  Form: TForm;  
  I: Integer;  
begin  
// Split up in a valid form and a valid component name  
  P := Pos('.', Name);  
  if P = 0 then  
  begin  
    raise Exception.Create('No valid form name given');  
  end;  
  FormName := Copy(Name, 1, P - 1);  
  CompName := Copy(Name, P + 1, High(Integer));  
  Found    := False;    
  // find the form  
  for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do  
    begin  
      Form := Screen.Forms[I];  
   // case insensitive comparing  
      if AnsiSameText(Form.Name, FormName) then  
        begin  
          Found := True;  
          Break;  
        end;  
    end;  
  if Found then  
    begin  
      for I := 0 to Form.ComponentCount - 1 do  
        begin  
          Result := Form.Components[I];  
         if AnsiSameText(Result.Name, CompName) then Exit;  
        end;  
     end;  
  Result := nil;  
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AV occurs because you are destroying a component (MyBitBtn) while it is still handling Windows messages. The solution is to postpone the destruction until later via `PostMessage`, similar to this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Variants,
  Classes,
  Graphics,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  Dialogs,
  ExtCtrls,
  StdCtrls;

const
  UM_DESTROYPANEL = WM_APP + 623; // some "unique" number; UM = user message

type
  TConf = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  strict private
    procedure UMDestroyPanel(var Message: TMessage); message UM_DESTROYPANEL;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Conf: TConf;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TConf.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, UM_DESTROYPANEL, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TConf.UMDestroyPanel(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Panel1.Free;
end;

end.
```

If needed you can use wParam and lParam to pass through parameters like so:

```
procedure TConf.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, UM_DESTROYPANEL, WPARAM(Panel1), 0);
end;

procedure TConf.UMDestroyPanel(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  TObject(Message.WParam).Free;
end;
```

**EDIT:**
In your situation I'd probably rewrite `TConf.CloseCurrentPanel` like this:

```
procedure TConf.CloseCurrentPanel(Sender: TObject);
var
  panelComp: TComponent;
begin
  panelComp := FindComponentEx('Conf.MyPanel'+ IntToStr(TBitBtn(Sender).Tag);
  PostMessage(Handle, UM_DESTROYPANEL, WPARAM(panelComp), 0); 
end;
```

Alternatively you can pass through the Tag (might be the better solution because there's less casting involved):

```
procedure TConf.CloseCurrentPanel(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, UM_DESTROYPANEL, TBitBtn(Sender).Tag, 0);
end;

procedure TConf.UMDestroyPanel(var Message: TMessage);
var
  panelComp: TComponent;
begin
  panelComp := FindComponentEx('Conf.MyPanel'+ IntToStr(Message.WParam));
  panelComp.Free;
end;
```

AFAICT the `Application.ProcessMessages` isn't needed.

Comment: One more question about this ... not start another topic.  Can you tell me how to use my FindComponentEx to find the specific panel so i can delete it throught wParam or lParam... thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TConf.CloseCurrentPanel(Sender: TObject);   
var     
   panelComp: TComponent;   
 begin     
   panelComp := FindComponentEx('Conf.MyPanel'+ IntToStr(TBitBtn(Sender).tag);  
   //Where you need to determine 'PanelComp' if there are.
   if Assigned(panelComp) and (PanelComp is TPanel) then
     TPanel(panelComp).Free;  
   Application.ProcessMessages;   
end;
```

Comment: If the FindComponentEx function is to find the right components, you can check what you TsPanel.Destroy inside.To be a breakpoint debugging will be easier to find the problem.